# issue with pinto.js overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I found the following plugin online: https://github.com/MaxLawrence/Pinto
It's a masonry like plugin. The thing is the first time it loads, it overlaps the items like this: [image: items overlapped]

and then i resize the window it does exactly as it should do the first time it loads haha.

[image: items right]

How can i fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your answer, this overlap issue was driving me crazy two.
You just need to to wrap the pinto call with an $(window).load() function. Try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  //pinto plugin call function goes here
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah that was pretty much the solution haha i actually used a plugin called imagesLoaded which checks of the images loaded and then call the pinto function , thanks :)